# Can defensive copies by used the assist with thread-safety?

Tags: java, thread-safety, defensive-copy

Is making a defensive copy of the fileName argument necessary in this example?

```
public static Context getInstanceFromFile(final String fileName) 
throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, ContextException {
    if (fileName == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("The fileName argument is null.");
    }
    return instance.loadParametersFromFile(String.valueOf(fileName));
}
```

In theory, another thread can modify the fileName before the `loadParametersFromFile` method is called. Is the same not true before `String.valueOf(fileName)` is called?

How can I ensure the value passed in fileName is still the same when loadParametersFromFile is called?

Comment: Modify a `String`? No, that's not possible, no need to copy anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, Strings are immutable and there's no way for another thread to modify the value of your `fileName` reference (since it's local to the calling method), so a defensive copy brings absolutely no benefit here.

In general, defensive copies can help to avoid such scenarios, provided there are done at the right time (when no other thread can modify the instance *while* the copy is running). A better idea for defense, as illustrated by this very `String` example, is to make passed classes immutable.

Answer (score 1):

No, in Java, Strings are immutable (unless you are hacking it with reflection). There is no need to safe-copy it.